# How to list only top level directories in azure storage using ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using below library to get all blobs in azure storage

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ruby

First, I want to get only top level directories in a container

```
    blob_client = Azure::Storage::Blob::BlobService.create(
      storage_account_name: account_name,
      storage_access_key: account_key
    )
```

I can get all blobs using below code

```
    blob_client.list_blobs(container_name)
```

But that's not what I want.

I want to loop all blobs under the loop of top level directories

```
    top_level_directories = blob_client.list_top_level_directories(container_name)
    top_level_directories.each do |directory|
        blobs = directory.list_blobs
        ...
    end
```

Above code is showing the strategy I want to loop. But that's not real code :)

Thanks

Comment: https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-ruby/Azure/Storage/Blob/BlobService.html
Here's one of useful online reference for this library

Comment: Please refer to https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-ruby/Azure/Storage/Blob/Container.html#list_blobs-instance_method